# Timezone in Store Hours Plugin

Tags: plugins, timezone

I am located in Austria using Pixel & Tonic's Store Hours Plugin. The Timezone in Craft's settings is set to UTC+1 (CET) - Europe/Vienna.

When I type in that it's opened from 3 - 6pm it outputs that it's opened from 2 - 5pm.

I guess that it is outputting the UTC but I can't really figure out why and how to fix it.
Is that possibly a bug in the plugin or is it meant to be adjusted in the template anyway?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Per [Brad's answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6577/45), this is a bug in the plugin. So we'll close this thread as a "bug report".

Comment: helloneele, I submitted a pr that fixes this bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a bug in the Store Hours plugin.  I've created an issue in the repo here so we can keep track of it: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/StoreHours/issues/3